# Managing featured content the drupal way

Tags: workflows

I currently have a homepage layout similar to the illustration below:
[image: my current homepage layout]

The featured nodes are all Views in separate block regions displaying a teaser. I'm using  a taxonomy term to filter in the specific node that I want appearing there.

As I'm new to Drupal, I'm wondering if:

a) My choice of using 4 separate block regions was wise. Would it have been wiser to use a view that shows a grid of 4 teasers?

b) If there is a better way of displaying featured content in the region below the slider (such as a 4 column panel)

Any insights into an effective workflow here would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Without describing what your goals are and what problems you are having, it is very difficult to suggest a "better" approach.  I don't think this question can be answered as it stands right now.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I'm not having any particular problems, however as I mentioned I'm very new to Drupal in general was simply wanting to see if my approach thus far makes sense when compared to the approaches of more experienced drupallers (perhaps like yourself). I'm fairly certain this layout isn't anything new. Perhaps a simpler way to explaining this post is: is my approach efficient and do you see any potential issues arising in the future?

Comment: @PatrickKenny how about this: my goals are 1) to allow a simple workflow for my clients to feature content in one of the 'featured node' spots, 2) to make sure that I'm not generating excess and wasted mark-up by creating four block regions as opposed to some other ingenius method :)

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to make a simple workflow for your clients, you have to take into account your clients' general ability to use the Web.  What is easy for one client may be very difficult for another, so it's hard to say which workflow is superior.  For example, when I set up a Drupal website for a CS professor, very little customization was required; on the other hand, when I set up Drupal for my grandfather, I had to do a lot of workflow customization to remove options and simplify things.

As far as easily allowing content to be "Featured," I usually set it up with Flags.  This is a pain to set up but is very simple for end users.  Basically, you have a flag for each section you want to feature.  This flag should allow you to flag nodes of the content type you want to feature.  Then you create a rule using the Rules module that trims the flag to 1; this means that only one piece of content can have the flag at any given time (assuming you only want to flag one piece of content per section).  Then users with the appropriate permissions can simply flag the content that they wish to feature and it will automatically be featured.  Advanced users probably don't need this, but for users with limited computer skills it may be helpful.

As for your concerns about excessive markup, Drupal in general generates lots of wasteful markup.  There are solutions like the Fences module and Semantic Views to try to slim it down, but in general I would not worry about this; you would have to have a huge amount of traffic before the time you spent trying to slim down the markup paid off.